# ansible json filter list

Tags: ansible, yaml, jmespath, json-query

I'm trying to filter out running services from the output of scan_services module (or service_facts in >= 2.5). The output of this module is something like this:

```
    "ansible_facts": {
    "services": {
        "NetworkManager-dispatcher.service": {
            "name": "NetworkManager-dispatcher.service",
            "source": "systemd",
            "state": "running"
        },
        "NetworkManager-wait-online.service": {
            "name": "NetworkManager-wait-online.service",
            "source": "systemd",
            "state": "stopped"
        },
        "NetworkManager.service": {
            "name": "NetworkManager.service",
            "source": "systemd",
            "state": "running"
        },
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is to list only the service names of the ones that are state: running... 
This code doesn't seems to work at all :/

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name : Scan current services status
    scan_services:
    register: running_services
  - name: print
    debug: var=item
    with_items: "{{ running_services.|json_query('ansible_facts.services.[?state=='running'].name')}}"
```

...but I think I'm somewhere near.
I guess something is missing in this json_query :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jmespath expression returning a list with the name of running services is this :

```
ansible_facts.services.* | [?state == `running`].name
```

Comment: "msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ansible_facts.services.* | [?state == `running`].name}}",

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
- name: Get Service Facts
  service_facts:

- name: Get running services
  set_fact:
    services_runnig: "{{ ansible_facts | json_query('services.* | [?state == `running`].name') }}"

- name: Debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ services_running }}"
```